# How do i set timestamp to specific cells everytime i open my google sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

How do I set a timestamp to multiple specific cells every time I open my document using script?

Lets say I want to set the current date and time on every cell from A2 to A25 how do I achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function initTimeStamps() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheets()[0];
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,24,1);//This is the range that receives timestamps
  var vA=rg.getValues();//This gives me access to the values
  var ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    vA[i][0]=ts;
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);//This is where the values are written back into the spreadsheet
}

function setupOnOpenTrigger() {//Run this once to setup the trigger
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  if(!isTrigger('initTimeStamps')) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('initTimeStamps').forSpreadsheet(ss.getId()).onOpen().create();
  }

}

function isTrigger(funcName){
  var r=false;
  if(funcName){
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++){
      if(funcName==allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction()){
        r=true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

[class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) Read this to learn how to setup ranges.

You can also setup triggers from the edit/current project triggers menu.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But i could not get this to work. I tried copy your code to a blank script page and then save it but theres no timestamp at all when i reopen my document.

Comment: Did you run the setTimeBasedTrigger function once? I put a comment in the code but perhaps you couldn't see it.  And actually I just realized it's not a time based trigger but it should still work.

Comment: I changed it to  `setupOnOpenTrigger()` but the function still the same

Comment: Ye i saw it, i couldnt figure out how to run it. I tried to copy just that code into a new sheet and run that but i guess thats the wrong way to do it. I lack a bit of knowledge in coding. Would be great if u could tell me how to run it.

Comment: After you setup the trigger then just close the spreadsheet and open it up again.

Comment: Thats the part i dont get. How do i run the setup trigger?

Comment: In the top  of the script editor there is a select function drop down where you can pick which function to run.  After selecting the function you want to run the press the Triangular button just to the left.  It's the run button. If you press the spider looking button that puts you in debug mode and allows you to single step through a script.

Comment: Thanks alot! Works like a charm! Which part of the code do i edit to change the A2 to A25 if i want more timestamps maybe to 30 or more later on? Just so i know where to change the value? thanks again!

Comment: try changing this - 
var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,24,1);
to this -
var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,ss.getLastRow()-1,1);  

this way the number of rows will match always...